# This app was built for an older version of Android and doesn't include the latest privacy protections

Tags: android, apk, target-sdk, google-play-protect

Today I started to get this annoying message (when installing APK outside the Google Play):

> This app was built for an older version of Android and doesn't include
> the latest privacy protections

[image: Google play message]

What is this message? What should we do?

I believe that it's because of the `targetSdkVersion` but can't find anything about it.

**^^^^ UPDATE ^^^^**

It turns out that when I changed `targetSdkVersion` from 24 to 26 - the message disappeared.

Comment: have u found any solution for this? then pls help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Google started to enforce using minimum `targetSdkVersion` of `26` for APK installed outside the Google Play Store.

So you'll have to updated your targetSdkVersion in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in your project.

Comment: Playing with Android 14 Beta 3 and targetSdkVersion is minimum at '28' now.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are having this problem even after updating the targetSdk to the latest version, make sure your "compileSdk" is written correctly.
I upgraded my Gradle and the "compileSdkVersion" was deprecated. After changing it to compileSdk, the pop-up stopped appearing.

Change

```
compileSdkVersion
```

To

```
compileSdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had your problem
To fix the problem, just put your target SDK on the latest version

for example

```
android {
namespace 'ir.galaxycell.kako'
compileSdk 33

buildFeatures{
    dataBinding true
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.galaxycell.kako"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```